# Is it better practice to use text of an element or attribute of an element in xml?

Tags: xml

I need to design an xml to create objects in runtime for a UI. It's a refactoring of a project with a pretty messed up structure.

The actual design is similar to this:

```
<combobox label="foo" pos=(10, 10)>
    <item label="bar">
    ...
</combobox>
```

The person who designed this does not have to implement the parser for it and my approach would be something like:

```
<combobox>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>10</y>
    <text>foo</text>
    ....
</combobox>
```

This would be more intuitive, since it relates more to the objects that need to be constructed when parsing the file.

But since it is hard to convince the projects owner i'm asking myself what really is the difference, advantages and disadvantages between those both.

Comment: Hmmm... My only objection against the actual design would be the `pos` attribute (looks like you also forgot the double quotes there), because it requires an additional text parsing step to get the `x`/`y` data out. Other than that, I don't really see why attributes would be harder to parse than elements.

Comment: If this is the only difference i would also stick to the actual design.

Comment: http://xml.coverpages.org/elementsAndAttrs.html